# Permanently change Table column order

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is it possible to permanently change the order of columns of shapefiles and other data formats like geopackage within qgis?

I have tried to do so using the settings in layer properties. but this setting only applies to the current qgis session and is not actually coded into the shapefile itself. Table manager is too risky since it often destroyed my data.

Comment: Have you tried Processing --> QGIS geoalgorithms --> Vector table tools --> Refactor fields?

Comment: Seems like I have not done enough research! Thanks a lot. You solved this issue for me!

Comment: Not sure why this is considered off-topic. It answered my question today, and it has been viewed 2000 times!